# Are there any rules for missing words in English questions or affirmative statements?

Tags: grammaticality, speech, conversation

In some sentences we don't use some words:

For example:

1. Instead of:  "Do you want a ride?"

   We say:      "Want a ride?"
2. Instead of:  "I'm just coming. Hang on!"

   We say:      "Just coming. Hang on!"

Is there any rule for how we can make them short?

Comment: Try reading up on *ellipsis*. If context allows listeners to easily (and probably subconsciously) supply the missing words, we often omit them. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipsis_(linguistics)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there's a rule.  In casual conversation, omit subject "I" in a declarative statement, but omit subject "you" in a question.  "(Do you) want some good advice?"  "(I) got some for you."  Omit inverted "do" or "are" auxiliaries in second person questions. "(Are you) coming with us?"

Answer (score 1):

I think that anytime that it is clear from the context, we omit words.

Example:
Someone says "Can you help me out?"
I don't have to answer  "It's no problem for me to help you out" — it is sufficient to say "No problem".
It is understood from the context that "It's" no problem because the word "it's" clearly refers back to what the speaker asked.
Similarly, I don't have to say "for me" because the speaker was speaking to me.
Lastly, I don't have to say "to help you out" because that is what you asked me to do.
Therefore, all I have to say is "no problem" to express all of these things!

Answer (score 0):

Well, to be honest , there is no such rule. They are just called 'shorthands'. We use them to make our meaning clear and as short as possible.

**Shorthand** — [M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/shorthand)

> *noun* 2. a short or quick way of showing or saying something